# Last year's totals won't group by hour

Tags: powershell, sql-server-express

I have a PowerShell script with a query to display yesterday's totals, as well as last year's same day totals, by hour for comparison. Yesterday's totals display by hour fine, but last year's list the entire sum for each hour. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
 $sql1 = "

    USE STORESQL
        
            SELECT FORMAT(TRS.F254, 'MM-d-yyyy') AS 'Date',


                   'Time' = CASE 
                        WHEN TRS.F01 = 06 THEN '6 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 07 THEN '7 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 08 THEN '8 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 09 THEN '9 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 10 THEN '10 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 11 THEN '11 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 12 THEN '12 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 13 THEN '1 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 14 THEN '2 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 15 THEN '3 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 16 THEN '4 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 17 THEN '5 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 18 THEN '6 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 19 THEN '7 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 20 THEN '8 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 21 THEN '9 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 22 THEN '10 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 23 THEN '11 PM'
                   END,


                   SUM(TRS.F65) AS 'Total Sales',

                   
                   (SELECT SUM(TRS.F65) FROM RPT_HOU AS TRS 
                    JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
                    JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057
                    WHERE TRS.F1031= 'D' AND 
                    TRS.F254 BETWEEN '$startDateLastYear' and '$startDateLastYear' AND
                    TRS.F1034 BETWEEN '2' and '2' AND
                    TRS.F01 BETWEEN '08' and '22' AND
                    LNK.F1000 NOT IN ('DSM', 'PAL', 'RAL', 'XAL')) AS 'Past Total Sales',


                    SUM(TRS.F64) AS 'Transactions',

                       
                   (SELECT SUM(TRS.F64) FROM RPT_HOU AS TRS 
                    JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
                    JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057
                    WHERE TRS.F1031= 'D' AND 
                    TRS.F254 BETWEEN '$startDateLastYear' and '$startDateLastYear' AND
                    TRS.F1034 BETWEEN '2' and '2' AND
                    TRS.F01 BETWEEN '08' and '22' AND
                    LNK.F1000 NOT IN ('DSM', 'PAL', 'RAL', 'XAL')) AS 'Past Transactions',



                   (round(SUM(TRS.F65)/SUM(TRS.F64), 2)) AS 'Avg Basket Size',



                   (SELECT(round(SUM(TRS.F65)/SUM(TRS.F64), 2)) FROM RPT_HOU AS TRS 
                    JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
                    JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057
                    WHERE TRS.F1031= 'D' AND 
                    TRS.F254 BETWEEN '$startDateLastYear' and '$startDateLastYear' AND
                    TRS.F1034 BETWEEN '2' and '2' AND
                    TRS.F01 BETWEEN '08' and '22' AND
                    LNK.F1000 NOT IN ('DSM', 'PAL', 'RAL', 'XAL')) AS 'Past Avg Basket Size'



        
            FROM RPT_HOU AS TRS 
                    JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
                    JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057

            WHERE TRS.F1031= 'D' AND 
                    TRS.F254 BETWEEN '$startDate' and '$startDate' AND
                    TRS.F1034 BETWEEN '2' and '2' AND
                    TRS.F01 BETWEEN '08' and '22' AND
                    LNK.F1000 NOT IN ('DSM', 'PAL', 'RAL', 'XAL')

            GROUP BY TRS.F254, TRS.F01
            ORDER BY TRS.F254

    "
```

Output:

[image]